# display:'block' is not working as it supposed to be

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

I want the table to be visible only after the submit button clicks. But It's not staying on the screen as it is supposed to be. Once I click the submit button, the table comes up for a second and then again becomes invisible. Please let me know what I am doing wrong in my code. Also please let me know if there is any other way to do it.

```html
<div style="margin-left: 2rem;">
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn" onclick="hide()">
</div>


<div style="margin-top: 4rem; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-content: center;">
  <table style="display: none;" id="table">
    <tbody>

      <tr>

        <th scope="row">Profile No. : </th>

        <td>{{ProfileUID}}</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <th scope="row">Name : </th>

        <td>{{Name}}</td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>



<script>
  function hide() {

    let btn = document.getElementById("btn");

    let table = document.getElementById("table");

    if (table.style.display === 'none') {

      table.style.display = 'block';

    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: FYI: The default display value for a table is `table` not `block`.

Comment: You have a Syntax error in your **hide** function. You close the curly bracket of the **if**-clause, but not of the function.

Comment: "_the table comes up for a second and then again becomes invisible_" tells, that the submit button is actually inside of a form element. The form is submitted, and as a default action, browser navigates to the current page (or the value of the action attribute of the form is the current location). Don't use button type of submit, if you don't want to submit the form.

Comment: @Teemu thanks for clearing that out.  I confirmed that it was caused because the button is inside the form. But I want to submit the form as well as want the same thing to happen over there. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Form is a link, you can't submit a form, and stay on the current page. Search for AJAX to send the data and stay on the current page.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code and it works now -

```html
<div style="margin-left: 2rem;">
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn" onclick="hide()">
</div>


<div style="margin-top: 4rem; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-content: center;">
  <table style="display: none;" id="table">
    <tbody>

      <tr>

        <th scope="row">Profile No. : </th>

        <td>{{ProfileUID}}</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <th scope="row">Name : </th>

        <td>{{Name}}</td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>



<script>
  function hide() {

    let btn = document.getElementById("btn");

    let table = document.getElementById("table");

    if (table.style.display === 'none') {

      table.style.display = 'table';

    }}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please point me out exactly in which part I was making the mistake?

Comment: @akc121 you had a syntax error in your code + I have changed `block` to `table`. Also, if my answer helps you, please mark as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

your code has a syntax problem. function hide is **missing curly braces**. Hope the below code can help you.

```js
 function hide() {

        let btn = document.getElementById("btn");

        let table = document.getElementById("table");

        if (table.style.display === 'none') {

          table.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
    <div style="margin-left: 2rem;">
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn" onclick="hide()">
    </div>


    <div style="margin-top: 4rem; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-content: center;">
      <table style="display: none;" id="table">
        <tbody>

          <tr>

            <th scope="row">Profile No. : </th>

            <td>{{ProfileUID}}</td>

          </tr>

          <tr>

            <th scope="row">Name : </th>

            <td>{{Name}}</td>

          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
```